# What is this climber called?

Tags: identification

Is it a fast grower? Can it be planted in zone 9 and in climate that's hot and dry with little rainfall?[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a Parthenocissus; whether it's Parthenocissus quinquefolia (common name Virginia creeper) or Parthenocissus triscuspidata (common name Boston ivy) is impossible to tell from your images because the leaves cannot be seen clearly. P. triscupidata has ovate leaves with usually three points, whereas P. quinquefolia has slightly larger palmate leaves with usually five points.

Virginia creeper will grow in USDA zones 2-9, so you might just about get away with it, but Boston Ivy is listed as suitable for zones 2-8. The other thing to note about these plants is, they only turn that glorious red colour in autumn/fall IF temperatures fall low enough, so if your fall is mild and temperatures don't go much below, say, 10 degrees C (50 degrees F) then the leaves will simply go yellowish brown before shedding. In the UK's variable climate, some years these turn bright red during September/October if the temperature is low enough, but in other, milder years, only some parts might turn vaguely red and the rest just doesn't produce those vivid tints. http://www.newmoonnursery.com/plant/Parthenocissus-quinquefolia

These plants, although they can be a little slow to get going in the first year or so, are extremely vigorous as they mature, and need regular attention as they get larger up the front of a house to ensure they do not infiltrate inside the house - entering through any gaps in the brickwork, doorways, windows and particularly under the roof into any loft space is not uncommon. It will certainly need to be rigorously pruned back to leave windows, doors and the top of the house clear on at least an annual basis, if not twice a year. They do not damage brickwork, provided the brickwork and mortar is in very good condition prior to planting; flaking brickwork and loose mortar joints/pointing  will be damaged otherwise. Note also that, although they attach themselves to whatever they can as they get larger, initially they will need support to keep them against a wall or fence.